# How to detect changes in Face ID?

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

I'm working on an iOS app that uses Face ID to access the app, but when they change their face id (add or remove), I want to detect that and get them to use their password (I've already built the password thing) before being able to use face id again. I know that I should be using kSecAccessControlBiometryCurrentSet (found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/ksecaccesscontrolbiometrycurrentset)), and that the flag gets invalidated when the user adds or removes a face, or changes their enrolled face. However, I'm not sure how any of that kSecAccessControlBiometryCurrentSet stuff works because I haven't found too much on it.

So I guess my question is what is the recommended way to detect changes in Face ID? And can I retrieve the current state of the kSecAccessControlBiometryCurrentSet flag, and see if its invalidated?

Oh and by the way, I've seen this on apps like lastpass, so I think its possible.

If you have any questions whatsoever (I bet my question was pretty hard to understand), feel free to ask :D

Thanks :D

Comment: Hey, just noticed the close vote, if there's something wrong with my question I would really like to know how I can improve, beecause sadly for now, I cannot read your mind. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add a secret to keychain and specify `kSecAccessControlBiometryCurrentSet`. Then, when you attempt to retrieve the secret, the retrieval will fail if there has been a change to the biometric database.

Comment: Hey @Paulw11! That sounds about right... could you send a link explaining how to add a secret to keychain and specify kSecAccessControlBiometryCurrentSet? Or something like that... Thanks!